# Find $a\in (0,1)$, $b\in (1,\infty)$ and $c\in (2,\infty)$ such that $a^2c+b=2a-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering if the solution set of the following problem exists in $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $a\in (0,1)$, $b\in (1,\infty)$ and $c\in (2,\infty)$ . Does a solution set of the below inequality exists? If yes, what is it? If no, what is the reason?

$$a^2c+b= 2a-1.$$

Note: I have edited the question, since first answer shows that the solution does not exists. I change the inequality to equality.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @SeraPhim I have tried fixing the values of $a$ and $b$. Later I realized that is not what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose such a triple $(a,b,c)$ exists.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
a^2c+b\le 2a-1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^2c+1< 2a-1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a^2c < 2a-2
\end{align*}
contradiction, since $a^2c$ is positive and $2a-2$ is negative.

Comment: This is a nice answer. Thank you.

Comment: However, I have made some edits in the question.

Comment: Since the inequality always fails, and since it's non-strict, equality also fails.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the update.